# Combined positive integer less than or equal to

Tags: python, arrays, list, integer, addition

I have a list of up to 1000 integers and I want the integer value that is closest to 1000 for the sum of any possible combination of integers from the list.

For `[900,500,498,4,8,10,600]` the expected result would be 1002 because 500+498+4=1002.

Comment: no the sum closest to 1000. For exampel 500+498+4=1002

Comment: How Close it should be?...

Comment: You should edit your question and more clearly specify what _exactly_ you need. For example, why not `500+498`, it’s equally close to 1000 as `500+498+4`.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that 500 + 498 = 998 is just as valid an answer as 1002 for your example, because both these numbers are equally close to 1000 and you just missed that. If you look for the maximum value if there are two possible solutions, that's an easy fix.

```
from itertools import combinations, chain

lst = [900, 500, 498, 4, 8, 10, 600]
c = chain(*(list(combinations(lst, i)) for i in range(1, len(lst) + 1)))
result = min(c, key = lambda x: abs(sum(x) - 1000))
print(sum(result)) # 998
```

Comment: ty :) how should I do if I insted whant 1002?

Comment: @Vilgot_Puff You could change `abs(sum(x) - 1000)` to `(abs(sum(x) - 1000), -sum(x))`

Comment: @Vilgot_Puff then you did it wrong. `result = min(c, key = lambda x: (abs(sum(x) - 1000), -sum(x)))`. For efficiency, consider defining the key function outside of the call to `min`, computing the sum twice is a little redundant, but an easy fix.

Comment: It works but "c = chain(*(list(combinations(lst, i)) for i in range(1, len(lst) + 1)))" gives a memory error if I use a list of more then 8 integers.